# How do I tie in my image handler with an image control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been looking around and reading about handlers, but I don't fully understand how to implement them for my situation.

I want display a screenshot from the user's clipboard. I already have code that retrieves the image from the clipboard into a bitmap format. This is what I have:

```
var dataobj = new DataObject();
dataobj = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();

System.Drawing.Image img = dataobj.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap) as System.Drawing.Image;
original = (System.Drawing.Image)img.Clone();

img = resizeImage(img, new Size(670, 500));
String s = "c:/Temp/temp.png";
img.Save(s, ImageFormat.Png);
Image1.ImageUrl = s;
Image1.DataBind();
```

My problem was that I am not able to save the images to the hard disk.

My first question is will an image handler help me in this situation?

if it will, how do I modify that code and tie it into my image handler with this code:

```
public class getmyimage : IHttpHandler 
{
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
  {
    HttpResponse r = context.Response;
    r.ContentType = "image/png";
    // Write the requested image
    r.WriteFile("temp.png");
  }

  public bool IsReusable
  {
    get { return false; }
  }
}
```

Comment: If this is ASP.NET, how are you capturing the users clipboard on the server?

Comment: Creating a new STA thread captures the user's clipboard on the server. I guess I haven't tested it non-locally, but the clipboard was always returning null before I implemented this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello handlers http allow customers to redirect or rewrite requests, format headers of requests for security reasons, or display a banner in some forums. but for your example i think you don't need http handler

Answer (score 0):

Configure the handler in web.config file and assign the URL to ImageURL property or use generic handler file which is with "ashx" extension and if you use ASHX, you don't need to configure in web.config file. Assign ASHX file path to ImageURL property. If you want to render dynamic images make sure you cleare cache or use defferent URL in subsequant call otherwise you will get cached image. 
Here is blog entry.

http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5223/using-ashx-files-to-retrieve-db-images/

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/asp-net/17/10093602/how-to-populate-image-form-sql-to-image-control.aspx